# Python TypeError: Takes 0 positional argument but 1 was given

Tags: python, typeerror

I have the following error message saying:

```
Line 7  t = num_days_missed(n)
TypeError: num_days_missed(n) takes 0 positional argument but 1 was given.
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Much appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v2HG.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question to include the code as text instead.

Comment: `num_days_missed` is not defined to accept a parameter `n`.

Comment: Why did you define the `num_days_missed()` function to accept no arguments, then try to call it with an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Use my *incredibly* ***handy*** decorator, `@add_pos_args`:

```py
def add_pos_args(to_f):
    return lambda *args: to_f()


def num_days_missed(): ...


try:
    num_days_missed('hello')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


@add_pos_args
def num_days_missed(): print('WHOO-HOO!')


# A-OK!  C-:
num_days_missed('hello')
num_days_missed('hello', 'world!')
```

Output:

```
num_days_missed() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
WHOO-HOO!
WHOO-HOO!
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 19, `def num_days_missed()` is currently not accepting any parameter. It will be `def num_days_missed(n)`, now this function is ready to get parameter `n`.

Check the image-
[num_days_missed function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumeg.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score -1):

The function `num_days_missed` does not accept any parameters currently. So, to accept parameters, modify the line `def num_days_missed():` to `def num_days_missed(n):`